# Using Fisher Yates without redundant array values

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im using the fisher yates shuffle to randomize which array values will be used but when I use it in my full script it sometimes uses the same array value  I need a function that prevents it from using the same array value twice

this is the  shuffle using nested array

```
Array.prototype.shuffle =
function(){
        var i = this.length, j , temp;
        while (--i> 0){
            j= Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
            temp= this[j];
            this[i]= temp;
        }return this;

}
var rans = [
    [ "What is 10 + 4?", "12", "14", "16", "B" ],
    [ "What is 20 - 9?", "7", "13", "11", "C" ],
    [ "What is 7 x 3?", "21", "24", "25", "A" ],
    [ "What is 8 / 2?", "10", "2", "4", "C" ]
];
var questions = rans.shuffle();
```

this is the script which makes use of the array

```
var pos = 0, test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, correct = 0;

function _(x){
return document.getElementById(x);
}
// this function renders the test results
function renderQuestion(){
test = _("test");
if(pos >= questions.length){
    test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got "+correct+" of "+questions.length+"    questions correct</h2>";
    _("test_status").innerHTML = "Test Completed";
        pos = 0;
    correct = 0;
    return false;
}
_("test_status").innerHTML = "Question "+(pos+1)+" of "+questions.length;
question = questions[pos][0];
chA = questions[pos][1];
chB = questions[pos][2];
chC = questions[pos][3];
test.innerHTML = "<h3>"+question+"</h3>";
test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'> "+chA+"<br>";
test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'> "+chB+"<br>";
test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'> "+chC+"<br><br>";
test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Submit Answer</button>";
}
 function checkAnswer(){
choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
for(var i=0; i<choices.length; i++){
    if(choices[i].checked){
        choice = choices[i].value;
    }
}
if(choice == questions[pos][4]){
    correct++;
}
pos++;
renderQuestion();
}
window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion, false);
```

Comment: You mean you have an array with duplicates and you want one shuffled and without duplicate ?

Comment: You just need right implementation of that algorhitm: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/ e.g. : https://jsfiddle.net/Ldgpg3y5/

Comment: Well that's how random works. Unless you interfere you can get a high card or a royal flush twice... No guarantees. Which means you should consider combinatorics if you want no repetition.